Using trigonometry to compute the position of an object inside of a drone picture
Assume I have a certain picture taken aerially by a drone. The yaw, pitch, and roll of the drone gimbal are known, and so are the horizontal and vertical FoV of the camera. We also know the $x$, $y$, and $z$ coordinates the drone had while taking the picture.
In order to determine whether a point, given its $x, y, z$ coordinates (for example in UTM), is inside of the field of view of the image, I have been using the following algorithm:

Compute rotation matrices for yaw, pitch, and roll:

$$R_{\text{yaw}} = \begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\text{yaw}) & -\sin(\text{yaw}) & 0 \\
   \sin(\text{yaw}) & \cos(\text{yaw}) & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
$$R_{\text{pitch}} = \begin{bmatrix}
   \cos(\text{pitch}) & 0 & \sin(\text{pitch}) \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   -\sin(\text{pitch}) & 0 & \cos(\text{pitch})
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
$$R_{\text{roll}} = \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & \cos(\text{roll}) & -\sin(\text{roll}) \\
   0 & \sin(\text{roll}) & \cos(\text{roll})
   \end{bmatrix}
$$

Construct the combined rotation matrix (R) as the product of these three matrices:
$R = R_{\text{yaw}} \cdot R_{\text{pitch}} \cdot R_{\text{roll}}$

Compute the view vector as: \begin{bmatrix}
\text{object}_x - \text{drone}_x \\
\text{object}_y - \text{drone}_y \\
\text{object}_z - \text{drone}_z
\end{bmatrix}

Multiply $R^T$ by the view vector: $R^T \cdot view\_vector$

Calculate the vertical and horizontal angle of the object with respect to the drone point of view:


Let $t_1, t_2, t_3$ be the first, second, and third element of $R\cdot view\_vector$.
$$\theta_{\text{horizontal}} = \text{atan2}(t_2, t_1)
$$
$$\theta_{\text{vertical}} = \text{atan2}\left(t_3, \sqrt{t_1^2 + t_2^2}\right)
$$

The point is in the image if $-{fov\_horizontal \over 2} \leq \theta_{horizontal} \leq {fov\_horizontal \over 2} \land -{fov\_vertical \over 2} \leq \theta_{vertical} \leq {fov\_vertical \over 2}$. If so, we compute the relative pixels at which the object is located as:

$$
x\_rel = \frac{\theta_{horizontal} + {fov\_horizontal \over 2}}{fov\_horizontal}
$$
$$y\_rel = \frac{\theta_{vertical} + {fov\_vertical \over 2}}{fov\_vertical}
$$
We multiply $x\_rel$ and $y\_rel$ times the image's width and height respectively to finally get the $x, y$ position of the point(s) in the image.
After trying out this procedure with some real images and point coordinates, I find that it often gives quite inaccurate results.
For example, it appears that, for any given list of points and a dataset of images whose GPS positions are very close to each other (e.g. drone photos taken while flying, a couple of meters apart), if some of the points appear in some images, then the algorithm will detect all of them in all images. If I throw an image that is very far from the others in the dataset, it'll correctly not detect the points inside that image. So it has issues distinguishing from relatively short distances. The relative positions of the detected points seem to stay about the same from image to image, aside from their rotation and relative distances, which change according to the image's orientation and altitude. That being said, the problem seems to have something to do with scaling, as the points are less spread apart than expected and appear in nearby images even if they shouldn't, as if the camera had a much larger field of view than it does in reality.
Am I making any mistakes in the various steps? Is there a better way to accomplish this task altogether?

The difficulty here is that there may be a mistake in the ordering of roll, pitch and yaw, but without a worked example with the exact definitions you're using it's hard to tell. In terms of checks, I would first suggest adjusting the field of view to a single point and making sure that it then corresponds to the line you would expect it to. Then you can check the horizontal and vertical fields of view separately. In terms of an alternative method, I believe quaternions are the more commonly used approach here, you might want to look at them. And in terms of why your results may otherwise...

...[cont] be off, there may be an error introduced when you consider the drone as a point (which I think is what you're doing here). If you think about the solid defined as the full field of view, it will (I think) be the frustum of a square (?) pyramid. It may be that you should be considering the apex of this pyramid as your point location, though the amount of difference this makes will depend on the distances involved. I'm sure there will be literature about all this - it's not my area but is an interesting question!

@ChrisLewis I'll try to get out a worked example for more info. For now, here's some more observations: it appears that, for any given list of GCPs and a dataset of images whose GPS positions are very close to each other (e.g. drone photos taken while flying, a couple of meters apart), if the GCPs appear in some images, the algorithm will detect all of them in all images. If I throw an image that's very far from the others in the dataset, it'll correctly not detect the points inside that image. So it has issues distinguishing from relatively short distances

Also, it appears that the results are more accurate if I scale up the values of $\theta_{horizontal}$ and $\theta_{vertical}$, for example multiplying them by some arbitrary values such a 5. Then the points appear more spread out inside of the image (as you would expect) and some that shouldn't belong in the images are "thrown out" of the image. But then again, this means that there has to be some issue with how I'm computing the values to begin with. I've tried changing the order of yaw, pitch, and roll but it doesn't seem to improve things (the order I'm using seems the correct one).

[GCPs standing for ground control points, i.e. the "objects" I'm trying to detect inside the images]

I just shared a Python implementation of the algorithm outlined in my post, with a test image + GCP coordinates to try it. This could help better visualize the calculations being done. Feel free to try it with different data. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RyRqqgmpOCH7elqE4_spCjAD2h61NRmY?usp=sharing

I'll be going based off of this picture: the drone will be facing in the (positive) $x$ axis, the left side of the drone is in the (positive) $y$ axis, and the top of the plane is the (positive) $z$ axis.

Let $R = R_{yaw} R_{pitch} R_{roll}$ be the rotation matrix (depending on the 3 angles roll, pitch, yaw, as measured from the standard basis vectors) that rotates the plane so (as measured from the standard basis vectors) it attains those 3 orientation angles.
Let us translate so the plane is at the origin, and so the object is now at
$$\vec v =\begin{bmatrix}
\text{object}_x - \text{drone}_x \\
\text{object}_y - \text{drone}_y \\
\text{object}_z - \text{drone}_z
\end{bmatrix} $$
(which you call the "view vector").
Rotating everything back (using $R^{-1}$) so the drone is now facing the (positive) $x$ axis, the question is now to determine if $R^{-1} \vec v = R^\top \vec v$ is "close enough" to the $x$ axis (as quantified by the horizontal and vertical view angles).
Ok, so the mental picture is: my eye is at the origin, and I'm looking down the positive $x$ axis, and a point $\vec v$ is at $v_x e_1 + v_ye_2 + v_z e_3$, where $v_x$ sure as hell has got to be positive; i.e. the test point $\vec v$ is  $v_x$ units "forward" in the $x$ direction, $v_y$ units "left", and $v_z$ units "up".
To determine the vertical angle (as I understand it), $v_y$ doesn't matter. The right triangle is

so you get (in your notation)
$$\theta_{vert} = \arctan(v_z/v_x)$$
which you want to be in the interval
$$[-\frac{FOV_{vert}}{2}, +\frac{FOV_{vert}}{2}].$$
The picture containing both $\theta_{vert}$ and $\theta_{horiz}$ is

I think your calculation for  $\theta_{horiz}$ is fine. So the vertical angle is the only part where I think we disagree.
I also think it may be a good idea to not have hard cutoffs --- like for angles near the cutoff, give it a different color/marking to indicate that it's near the cutoff and hence could go either way, depending on measurement/rounding errors.

I have tried subbing my $\theta_{vert}$ formula for yours, but I'm pretty much getting the same results (aside from the points being slightly translated towards the top for some reason). It does look like there isn't much left to try at this point, everything seems to have failed...

By the way, thank you for the way you visualized the $\theta_{vert}$ angle for me, it makes much more sense to me now what it represents. Could you do the same for $\theta_{horiz}$? I'm having a hard time understanding how it related to the vertical angle and what it represents

@SamueleB. is there any way to test the measurement capabilities of the drone in a controlled setting? In my experience, the major roadblock is that sometimes we think we know what the machines are measuring, but testing thoroughly, it turns out they are measuring something different (as an artificial example of what I am talking about, imagine instead of the angle from the positive $z$ axis, they're measuring from the negative $z$ axis)

@SamueleB. I also think it might be a good idea to try to plot the positions of the drone, the orthogonal frame of the drone, the object, and the planes of view (from my other answer) in some 3D visualization. I.e. for testing purposes, just calculate everything and put it all in a 3D plot. That way you can see for yourself what the "pyramid of view" looks like in 3D space, and can judge for yourself with your own eyes which of the calculations produces something wrong.

Unfortunately, I have no means of testing the drone in a controlled environment. In fact, this algorithm is part of an app that is supposed to try and work well with images from any drone. I am doing some pre-processing of the EXIF data to try and make sure I am "normalizing" the data, such as some drones using negative pitch angles and others using positive angles, but at the end of the day it doesn't seem to be the culprit (with outright wrong data, it just doesn't produce any results, otherwise it produces kind of inaccurate results).

Also, I do believe that plotting and visualizing everything would help. I'm just not too sure how I would do that. I have no experience with 3d visualization programs.

@SamueleB. a very labor intensive way would be to choose a specific example data of position of drone, position of object, and orientation angles, and compute everything, and plot it by hand in Desmos https://www.desmos.com/3d. To do this you would have to do the vector based method in my other answer. I set up some example code here https://www.desmos.com/3d/sz7zf1vx1v

Here are some ideas I had. Generally, I tried to do things more with vectors instead of angles (in my experience in math, it's very rare to work with angles, and much more common to work with vectors). So I might calculate a lot more things than your original method. But this was just my attempt at clearly laying out all the quantities "on the table".
Drone originally at position $\vec p := (x,y,z)$. Let us translate (conceptually, it doesn't matter in the below calculation) so the drone is at the origin.

The first step is to calculate the orthogonal frame for the drone: the "forward facing direction (pilot's gaze)" $\vec d = (d_1,d_2,d_3)$, the "right-facing direction (pilot's outstretched arm to the right)" $\vec r = (r_1,r_2,r_3)$, and the "upward-facing direction (pointing out the top of the pilot's head)" $\vec u = (u_1,u_2,u_3)$.
These 3 vectors should be able to be calculated just from the 3 angles yaw, pitch, roll, and nothing else (i.e. no need to know actual position $\vec p$)
A large body of work has already been developed, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles. But we can develop it from scratch: composing the rotation matrices to get a rotation matrix $R$, the orthogonal frame is simply the result of applying $R$ to the standard orthonormal basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$ (also known as $\hat i, \hat j, \hat k$). For reference, here's an AI conversation I had for this step (since I have zero familiarity with these yaw, pitch, roll angles); it may serve as a helpful springboard.
If possible, it would be very good to test these calculations on your drone before doing any further calculations. Like have it oriented in several test positions for which you know $\vec d, \vec r, \vec u$ already, and see if the angles it measures and the calculations above give you back these correct $\vec d, \vec r, \vec u$ frame vectors.

We now calculate the 4 planes (or rather, the normal vectors to those planes) bounding the pyramidal region visible to the drone, using
the values $\theta_{horiz}$ and a $\theta_{vert}$ for the total horizontal and vertical angle available in the field of view.
Let $\vec v_t$ be the vector in the very top middle of the drone/pilot's field of view, so $\vec v_t = a_{tu} \cdot \vec u + a_{td} \cdot \vec d$ for some coefficients $a_{tu}, a_{td} >0$. (Because this whole line is the very top middle of the field of view, we can just normalize say $a_{td}=1$ to get one vector on this "line of view".) Drawing the relevant right triangle produces $\tan(\theta_{vert}/2) = \frac{a_{tu}\|\vec u\|}{a_{td}\|\vec d\|}$. So at this point, we know $\vec v_t$, a vector describing the very top middle "line of view".
Similarly, for $\vec v_r$ the very center right of the field of view has $\vec v_r = a_{rr}\cdot \vec r + a_{rd} \cdot \vec d$, where $\tan(\theta_{horiz}/2) = \frac{a_{rr}\|\vec r\|}{a_{rd}\|\vec d\|}$.
To calculate the plane bounding the top of my field of view, I just take the plane containing $\vec v_t$ and $\vec r$. Or in other words, to find the normal vector $\vec n_t$ to this plane, I take the cross product $\vec n_t = \vec v_t \times \vec r$.
In this way, I get normal vectors to all 4 planes (bounding the top, right, bottom, left of my field of view): $\vec n_t, \vec n_r, \vec n_b, \vec n_l$

Now, we translate so the drone is at $-\vec d$, so that when it is facing in direction $\vec d$, it is facing the origin, i.e. the origin should definitely be in the field of view. (This is a good way to have a "built in" test point.)
I get my 4 planes bounding the field of vision passing through $-\vec d$ perpendicular to each of the normal vectors: $\vec n_\bullet \cdot \Big(x-(-d_1), y-(-d_2), z-(-d_3)\Big)=0$ for $\bullet = t,r,b,l$.
Then, I plug in $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ and see which side of the inequality the origin is on, for all 4 of the planes. I get 4 inequalities $I_t, I_r, I_b, I_l$ to determine if a point $(x,y,z)$ is on the same side of these 4 planes as the point $(0,0,0)$, which we know for sure must be in the field of vision.

Finally, to determine if a sample point $\vec s = (s_1,s_2,s_3)$ is in the field of view of the drone at $\vec p = (p_1,p_2,p_3)$, we just have to translate it to the setting where the drone is at $-\vec d$, i.e. the translation given by adding $-\vec p - \vec d$ to everything.
In other words, set $(x,y,z)$ to be $\vec s - \vec p - \vec d$, and plug that into the 4 inequalities $I_t, I_r, I_b, I_l$, and they all return true, then indeed $\vec s$ is in the field of view!

It might be horrible to read through, but to me, this is conceptually the most transparent formulation of the entire problem. Everything worth calculating (i.e. everything in my mental model of the situation) is calculated.

Thank you for your contribution. Would you mind focusing a little more on my approach and highlighting what could possibly be causing the inaccuracies, and where I could improve it? Do you feel it's missing something crucial compared to your model? https://community.opendronemap.org/uploads/default/optimized/3X/a/b/abcf563644529cfac0e5e35511355fd40c46976a_2_1336x998.jpeg this picture shows some results. Points 1, 2, 3, and 5 are pretty close, but you would need some distortion (not just rotating and scaling the image) to match them. 4 is a false positive

However, a picture taken pretty close to the previous one, with just some rotation (yaw) yields much more inaccurate results: https://community.opendronemap.org/uploads/default/optimized/3X/8/f/8fb22da29e52db51edbd60cfbe14bed2a24bbde3_2_1380x918.jpeg what could be going on here?

@SamueleB. part of my answer is trying to break the problem into many substeps, at which point one could see if it's the data that's the issue. For example, in the first part calculating the orthogonal frame, uses only some of the data (not even about the field of view). If that already doesn't work, then that means the inaccuracy is in the yaw, pitch, roll angle measurement, in which case the whole thing is doomed. By breaking the problem down, we can see the first point of failure.
